# django remove item from shopping cart

Tags: django

I am following the shopping cart example from django ecommerce book and I am facing an issue when it comes to remove items from shopping cart, I cannot get to remove single items from the session.

This is part of my cart.py

```
class Cart(object):
    class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, itemid, product, quantity=1, price=0):
    self.itemid = itemid
    self.product = product
    self.quantity = quantity
    self.price = price
    self.totalprice = price * quantity
def remove_item(self, itemid):
    self.items = filter(lambda x: x.itemid != itemid, self.items)
```

views.py

```
def remove_from_cart(request, cart_item_id):
     cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
     cart.remove_item(int(cart_item_id))
     update_shopping_cart(request, cart)
     cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
     ctx = {'cart': cart}
```

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.5. Is anything wrong with the definition of the remove_item method? I have tried several options but coudn't make it work
Any hint would be appreciated.

EDIT: my update_shopping_cart method is:

```
def update_shopping_cart(request, cart):
    request.session['cart'] = cart
```

The view where the cart allows remove items:

```
def shopping_cart(request): 
    cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
        cart.remove_item(cart_item_id)
        update_shopping_cart(request, cart)
        cart = get_shopping_cart(request)   
        ctx = {'cart': cart} 
    render_to_response(...)
```

Comment: We need your `update_shopping_cart` method. I assume the latter is altering the session variable.

Comment: I have edited the post adding the update_shopping_cart method. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two issues:

1. Did you set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True`?
2. In the method

   ```
   def remove_from_cart(request, cart_item_id):

       cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
       cart.remove_item(int(cart_item_id))
       update_shopping_cart(request, cart)
       cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
       ctx = {'cart': cart}
   ```

you are actually fetching your data, then changing it to then **fetch again** the old data. Why do you do the second `cart = get_shopping_cart(request)`? That probably overwrites the changes you have just made.

Adapt the code as follows

```
def remove_from_cart(request, cart_item_id):
    cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
    cart.remove_item(int(cart_item_id))
    update_shopping_cart(request, cart)
    # cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
    ctx = {'cart': cart}
```

and adapt your `update_shopping_cart(request, cart)` as Greg suggests to

```
def update_shopping_cart(request, cart):
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    request.session.modified = True
```

Comment: An alternative might also be that the `update_shopping_cart should return the new session variable.

Comment: @lorenag83 please accept the answer if it works... and upvote it while you're at it :)

Answer (score 0):

Does adding this line help?

```
def update_shopping_cart(request, cart):
    request.session['cart'] = cart
    request.session.modified = True
```

Comment: No.. that doesnt change anything. I will add my cart view to see if there's anything wrong there